# Airline pilots and unplanned but not necessary manouevres

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning, rules-of-the-air

[This story](https://abcnews.go.com/International/pilot-turns-plane-giving-passengers-amazing-view-northern/story?id=97532769) details how an EasyJet captain flew a presumably unplanned circle to give everyone on board a look at the Northern Lights.

Are captains allowed to do this sort of thing on a whim, or would he or she have cleared it with ATC somewhere first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easyJet would be operating under Instrument Flight Rules (IFR) and most probably in controlled airspace.

> 3.6.2.1 Except as provided for in 3.6.2.2 and 3.6.2.4, an aircraft shall adhere to the current flight plan or the applicable
> portion of a current flight plan submitted for a controlled flight unless a request for a change has been made and clearance
> obtained from the appropriate air traffic control unit, or unless an emergency situation arises which necessitates immediate
> action by the aircraft, in which event as soon as circumstances permit, after such emergency authority is exercised, the
> appropriate air traffic services unit shall be notified of the action taken and that this action has been taken under emergency
> authority.
>
> *ICAO Annex 2 — Rules of the Air*

The crew would be required to seek clearance from the air traffic control unit before deviating from the established flight plan or previous clearance. (i.e. they would have been on a set course and set altitude).

Deviating without proper authorisation would not be standard procedure and could lead to potential safety risks or conflicts with other air traffic.

Furthermore, I’m not sure if this would have gone down very well with the easyJet operations team - increased fuel burn and potential to run late. However, the article does suggest that easyJet supported the move, though this could have just been a comment from the PR team.

(Also, I just wanted to highlight that decision-making in multi-pilot aviation involves both pilots, not solely the captain. While the captain serves as the final authority in making critical decisions, it is essential to recognise that the flight crew operates as a cohesive team. You make it sound like one person is calling all the shots here).

Comment: Thanks - I reckon Ryanair would deduct the fuel from their salary :)

Comment: No don’t be silly…….they would charge the passengers €50 per head for the “Northern Lights Experience.”

Comment: As for the fuel consumption and delay: flying a circle to offer passengers a perhaps unique experience is well worth the whopping couple of minutes of time it takes and $150 it costs.

Comment: @Jpe61 I’m not sure a job in ops for a low cost airline is for you my friend. At least, don’t bring this up in the interview.

Comment: @tedioustortoise: If the plane was ahead of schedule, and might have needed to circle later in the flight as a consequence, perhaps circling at higher latitudes might require less fuel per minute because of lower exterior temperatures than circling nearer the destination?

Comment: @supercat Typically the airports easyJet tends to land at will not have any issue with taking a flight in early. No requirement to hold later in the flight

Comment: @supercat a very good point!  If the winds are better than planned, they may arrive at the destination airport before their landing slot or gate would be ready.  So they'd be doing tracks anyway, just showing scenic Dumpsville instead of the Northern Lights. And what altitude are the hold stacks?  Not 35,000 feet I'll bet, so they'd be less fuel-efficient.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: I was being a little facetious with my suggestion, but making an extra circle at one part of the trip doesn't always imply using more fuel.  A bigger issue is that from what I understand the perceived need for air traffic control was a result of planes making slight sight detours over the Grand Canyon to give passengers a better view.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica just FYO landing slots or “gate ready” is really not applicable for the destination airports that easyJet would be landing into. If they are early, I can guarantee you the airports will almost always accept them without any issues.

Comment: @tedioustortoise That could well be. Mentally I equate them to Spirit or Southwest, which prefers quiet airports but flies into very difficult ones as well.

Comment: @tedioustortoise thanks for the advice 

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica a quiet airport doesn’t guarantee lack of difficulty, often it’s the opposite: short landing distances available, VFR traffic, less experienced controllers. (Context here is Europe)

Answer (score 5):

If they were coming from Iceland, they weren't in the North Atlantic Track System.

If they were on the NATs (North America to Europe non-stops only), this would have been out of the question, but on a non-NAT route well to the north like that, the option would have been available, but they would still get a clearance from the applicable Oceanic Controller before doing so.

Comment: They were smack in the middle of the ADS-B/SSR surveillance corridor between Iceland in and the UK. The turn was executed at FL370, in the nominal coverage of two SSRs (one Icelandic, one on the Faroe islands) three terrestrial ADS-B stations (one Icelandic, two on the Faroe islands) plus the space based Aireon ADS-B system, all feeding data to Iceavia control centre in Reykjavik. This is not Non-Radar airspace

Comment: Though I suspect they got a call from the chief pilot the next day, asking why they were wasting gas out there!

Comment: @DeltaLima  I forgot all about ADSB lol. It's been 13 years since my last IFR flight.

Comment: ATC's job is to keep airplanes from crashing into each other. They have no interest where a plane goes or what route it takes unless it interferes with other aircraft or with safety. Obviously it depends on the situation like in a TCA, and some amount of order is necessary. I'm interested in the concept of "getting permission" from ATC. Of course, in controlled airspace ATC ultimately decides, but I would think a controller can't deny a pilot's request "just because I don't want you to".  They may not like the additional workload, but if no other aircraft are affected why is it their concern?

Comment: @StevePemberton well they didn’t have a problem with it hence why the manoeuvre was allowed. Remember though that this is IFR flight, with a legal framework for the conduct of the flight, the traffic simply is controlled. For example, I can’t just drive my car any which way I want to on the road, I have to follow the rules of the road. Even though I might think it is better to go through a red traffic lightit’s probably best not to. Typically air traffic control have the best situational awareness to handle the positioning of aircraft in the sky from a safety and efficiency perspective.

Comment: '@tedioustortoise - yes as I mentioned some order is required. And I am talking about Class A airspace not TCA's or similar. Standard routes have been implemented to create some orderliness. But variances to the standard routes happens all the time. Most  variance requests are limited to enroute weather and wind, but that's airline policy. My question is does ATC care about the reason for the request? A pilot can request a change from standard route due to winds, but not for sightseeing? They can request to fly in a circle to burn off altitude, but not to give passengers a view of something?

Comment: A pilot can ask for anything within reason, & ATC can grant it, or not , & will normally try to accommodate you if there aren't any traffic flow conflicts. An OEM will negotiate geographic test area blocks with local ATC unit & you'll be cleared into it & within you can go wherever you want. You can request all sorts of things, like altitude block clearances, & ATC will grant it or won't, depending on whether they can work traffic around you. Whatever it is, it's a clearance and you have to follow the clearance, and if you want to deviate outside its boundaries, you have to get permission.

Comment: @John K - Another example are things like the final maiden flight of [the Queen](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/boeing-747-queen-crown-sky/index.html). I would guess in some cases ATC will put you down into denser less efficient air where other airliners are less likely. Or in the 747 example it was under 18,000 feet and presumably VFR.  But what I am referring to is a common misconception that ATC decides what routes planes take. Yes ATC is always in control, but it's a subtle nuance in semantics which requires detailed explanation. Similar to the statement "airplanes can fly themselves".

Comment: When you submit your IFR flight plan, you choose the route. 99% of the time, ATC will issue a clearance based on your flight planned route. Occasionally, they will amend your flight plan and assign a different routing. You will be warned of this when you call in for your clearance, because instead of just jotting "FPR" as you write out your clearance to read back, you're going to have to write down and read back correctly a different set of waypoints. They will normally respect your IFR reserves range limitations, but if they don't, you have to let them know you can't use that routing.

Comment: @John K - I live about 5 miles from the corridor from the northeast into Atlanta, which includes planes from Europe if they aren't going north because of the jet stream. From watching FlightRadar24 it seems like ATC often starts getting everyone into the conga line for ATL just past Washington D.C. I'm guessing that the initial flight plan filed is essentially direct to ATL, or at least direct to the typical first waypoint for the approach. Then I would think ATC immediately amends it into the line they are using at that time. Or does the amendment usually occur en route?

Comment: Do some reading on STARs, Standard Terminal Arrival procedures. Large airports have published STARs, for different arrival directions, and navigation methods. When your clearance is issued, it may or may not include a STAR tacked on to the end of the route. It has a set of waypoints, altitudes and speed limits that get you from the last enroute waypoint to one of the instrument approaches for that airport. Arriving airplanes from a particular direction will always seem to pass the same spot b/c they are flying that STAR. IFR protocols are designed to allow you to complete a trip with no comms.